# asp.net mvc многопоточность и autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

Приложение разделено на слои. В слое сервисов хочу использовать новый поток для того, чтобы юзер не ждал ответа от внешнего сервиса. Но также после реквеста в удаленный сервис хочу записать данные в базу. С базой работаю через фабрику контекста, репозитории и UnitOfWork

```
builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DataLayer).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
```

Таким образом, UnitOfWork не знает о репозитории, а репозиторий не знает о UnitOfWork, но фабрика отдает один экземпляр контекста для обоих конструкторов.

Собственно сложность в том, что в новом потоке контекст базы уже стёрт, потому что реквест окончен. Если же я передаю фабрику, которая вернет экземпляр сервиса, то контекст autofac уже стёрт, и он не может создать экземпляр. Как правильно создать фабрику, так чтобы в другом потоке она создала экземпляр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось проще, просто дополнительно использовал `Named` c `InstancePerDependency` для нужных классов и использовал их в фабрике для сервиса.